# Proof Reference - Polynomial interpolation at quadrature points

Tags: reference-request, orthogonal-polynomials, interpolation, quadrature

If $\left( p_n \right)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is a family of orthogonal polynoamials with respect to a measure $\mu$ on $[-1,1]$, and $\left( x_j, w_j \right)$ are the quadrature points and weights for the respective Gaussian quadrature rule, we can easily prove that 
$$ f_N (x) : \, = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1} \sum\limits_{j=1}^{N} p_n (x_j) f(x_j) w_j p_n (x) \, ,$$
is the interpolation polynomial of degree $N-1$ for $f$ at the quadrature points $x_1, \ldots x_N$.

**My question:** While I could prove it, I couldn't find a reference for this proof in any textbook. Could you help with that?

This is cross-posted from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2595490/161591) post in MSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, three possible references for the formula:

> P. J. Davis and P. Rabinowitz, Methods of Numerical Integration,
>   Computer Science and Applied Mathematics. Academic Press, New York,
>   1984 (see p.88)
>
> J. C. Mason and D. C. Handscomb, Chebyshev Polynomials, CRC Press, New
>   York, 2003 (see section 8.3.2 for the case of Chebyshev Polynomials)
>
> J. Shen, T. Tang, L-L. Wang, Spectral methods. Algorithms, analysis
>   and applications. Springer Series in Computational Mathematics, 41.
>   Springer, Heidelberg, 2011 (see Thm 3.9 p.64)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't find it in Davis and Rabinowitz, because I only have the 1967 edition. Could you write in what part is it, so I can look it up?

Comment: I think the formula appears in section 2.5.6 : Product integration rules.
But, in the 3rd reference, the book by Shen, Tang, Wang, the formula is maybe better presented.

Comment: Thanks, but we don't have it in our library...